# How do I trigger the redraw of a parent View when any of it's children are redrawn?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, android-widget

## Background

I have written a custom Android View based on a `LinearLayout` which I have called `ReflectingLayout`. The idea is fairly simple, to render a reflection effect below any child Views declared within the `ReflectingLayout`. e.g...

[image: Something like this]

I am achieving this by overriding `dispatchDraw()` in `ReflectingLayout` as follows:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(...); 
  Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

  // Draw child views to bitmap using tempCanvas
  super.dispatchDraw(tempCanvas);

  ...
  // some tranformations performed on bitmap
  ...

  // draw transformed image on to main canvas
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
}
```

## The Problem

If my `ReflectingLayout` contains, say, a `TextView` and I change the text content of that `TextView` the reflection effect is not updating.

I believe this is because Android will only redraw the `TextView` itself rather than all the parent views as well, meaning my overridden `dispatchDraw()` method does not get called.

**Is there any simple way to trigger the redrawing of a parent view in response to changes in any of it's child views?**

In particular, how can I make my `ReflectingLayout` be redrawn when child views are redrawn?

## Things I've already considered

- I've noticed that a new [`View.OnLayoutChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener.html) was added in API Level 11. Presumably this could be used to register a callback to the parent view and trigger a redraw(?). In any case, I need a solution which will work on API Level 7 upwards.
- I could simply extend `TextView` and any other View class I want to declare inside `ReflectingLayout` to invalidate their parent as they are redrawn, but this is a clunky solution.

Any help greatly received (including if you think the overall approach is wrong).

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try invalidating *(= mark for redraw)* your views by calling `invalidate()`? Either the whole `ReflectingLayout` or by writing a helper method that changes the textviews text and invalidates the reflection view after that?

Comment: That's the current hack I'm employing right now as a workaround in my activity. i.e. At the point I change the `TextView` I call `invalidate()` on the `ReflectingLayout`. I just don't want the `ReflectingLayout` to have to depend on the host activity to invalidate it - poor portability, encapulation etc.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a better solution to this?

Comment: I'm afraid the hack remains in place... :-(

Answer (score 7):

What about using `getParent()` method in your view? Something like this:

```
if (getParent() instanceof View)
    ((View) getParent()).invalidate();
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this problem. I figured out it was due to the new hardware acceleration support in 3.0+ The way I solved it was using `View#setLayerType` and using `LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`. In order to continue targeting API level 8 I used reflection to call this method on supporting android platforms. This solved the issue and now my custom ViewGroup draws properly when the children are invalidated.

I don't know if this will solve your problem exactly but it may help others who are also perplexed by this issue.

Reflection code, pretty basic:

```
try {
    Method method =
            CustomViewGroup.class.getMethod("setLayerType", new Class[] { Integer.TYPE, Paint.class });
    // 0x1 == LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE
    method.invoke(this, new Object[] { Integer.valueOf(0x1), null });
} catch(SecurityException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "reflectSetLayerType", e);
} catch(NoSuchMethodException e) { // don't care
} catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "reflectSetLayerType", e);
} catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "reflectSetLayerType", e);
} catch(InvocationTargetException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "reflectSetLayerType", e);
}
```